# MapStruct - Map Generic List to Non-Generic List containing different types

Tags: java, generics, mapping, mapstruct

I am attempting to use MapStruct to convert between 2 internal models. These models are generated from the same specification and represent a large tree-like structure that is constantly being added to. The goal of using MapStruct is to have an efficient, low (non-generated) code way of performing this conversion that stays up to date with additions to the specification. As an example, my models would look like:

```java
package com.mycompany.models.speca;

public class ModelSpecA {
    private String name;
    private int biggestNumberFound;
    private com.mycompany.models.speca.InternalModel internalModel;
    private List<com.mycompany.models.speca.InternalModel> internalModelList;
}
```

```java
package com.mycompany.models.specb;

public class ModelSpecB {
    private String name;
    private int biggestNumberFound;
    private com.mycompany.models.specb.InternalModel internalModel;
    private List internalModelList;
}
```

with all of the expected getters and setters and no-arg constructors.
MapStruct is able to generate code for the mapping extremely easily with the code looking like:

```java
interface ModelSpecMapper {
    ModelSpecB map(ModelSpecA source);
}
```

From unit testing and inspecting the generated code, the mapping is accurate and complete except in one regard: the mapping of the `internalModelList` member in each class. The generated code looks like the following:

```
...
if (sourceInternalModelList != null) {
    specBTarget.setInternalModelList( specASource.getInternalModelList() );
}
...
```

I.e. It is mapping from the generic List<com.mycompany.models.speca.InternalModel> to the non-generic List without doing model conversion. This passes at compile time and runtime in unit tests, but will cause errors in later code when we expect to be able to cast to the SpecB version of the model.

So far, I've investigated if it is possible to force a mapping of the parameterized type in the source to its corresponding type without using expensive reflection operations, which would eliminate the gains from using MapStruct as a solution. This is my first experience with MapStruct, so there may be an obvious solution I am simply unaware of. Adding an explicit mapping is infeasible as I need this to be forward compatible with future additions to the model including new Lists.

TLDR; How do I use MapStruct to convert the contents of a generic List to a non-generic List? E.g. `List<com.mycompany.a.ComplexModel> --> List` whose members are of type `com.mycompany.b.ComplexModel`.

Comment: This sounds like a major [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you want to use raw types unsafely?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- In effect, the classes ModelSpecA and ModelSpecB are themselves generated code for different service frameworks from a common specification. The service framework for SpecB is extremely legacy and is required to provide support for services written pre-Java 5. Hence, no generic support in the generated code. For reference, we have a Jackson-based solution currently that manages this through intermediary JSON  serialization, but is extremely slow.

Comment: Have you tried using Jackson to perform the mapping directly from type to type without going through the actual JSON intermediate? This isn't widely known, but it's supported.

Comment: have you tried defining a `List map(List<com.mycompany.models.speca.InternalModel> source)` method with the `@IterableMapping(elementTargetType=com.mycompany.models.specb.InternalModel.class)` annotation?
[see chapter 10.4 about determining result type for more information.](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#determining-result-type)

Comment: @BenZegveld This works perfectly for mappings where I already know where the issue will lie. It fails on forward-compatibility however when the common specification is updated to include new collection members. Of course the mapping can be updated for these new members, but this happens often enough that I'd like to sort out how to make it zero-touch forward compatible.

Comment: In case you are still looking for alternatives: I just read this line, `These models are generated from the same specification`. So couldn't you use that same specification to generate the Mapstruct mapping class with the required mapping methods? For example for each list generate the additional mapping method with annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions by @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-, I managed to successfully accomplish the mapping by using Jackson to perform the mapping directly from type to type, but that is tangential to the MapStruct problem. I was able to accomplish the stated goal of mapping a generic list to a non-generic list by adding a default mapping to my MapStruct mapper:

```java
     /**
      * Map a generic List which contains object of any type to a non-generic List which will contain objects
      * of the resulting mapping.
      * E.g. It maps a generic list of T to a non-generic list of contents mapped from T.
      * @param source Source generic List to map from.
      * @return A non-generic List whose contents are the contents of <i>source</i> with mapping implementation applied.
      * @param <T>
      */
     default <T> List mapGenericToNonGeneric(List<T> source) {
         if (source == null) {
             return null;
         }
         if (source.isEmpty()) {
             return new LinkedList();
         }
         // Handle the most common known cases as an optimization without expensive reflection.
         final Class<?> objectClass = source.get(0).getClass();
         if (ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(objectClass)) {
             return new LinkedList(source);
         }
 
         if (String.class.equals(objectClass)) {
             return new LinkedList(source);
         }
    
         try {
             Method mapperMethod = Stream.of(this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                     .map(method -> {
                         Parameter[] params = method.getParameters();
                         // If this method is a mapper that takes the type of our list contents
                         if (params.length == 1 && params[0].getParameterizedType().equals(objectClass)) {
                             return method;
                         }
                         return null;
                     })
                     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(null);
             if (mapperMethod != null) {
                 final List result = new LinkedList();
                 for (T sourceObject : source) {
                     result.add(mapperMethod.invoke(this, sourceObject));
                 }
                 log.info("Executed slow generic list conversion for type {}", objectClass.getName());
                 return result;
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
         return null;
     }
```

From inspecting the generated code and adding assertions to the type of each collection contents, this is passing my property-based testing suite. It still makes use of reflection to determine the parameterized type but is able to handle arbitrary additions to the model and outperforms the previous Jackson solution substantially.